# Identityserver4 openid-configuration omits host port running nginx reverse proxy

Tags: docker, nginx, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4

I am setting up an Identity server4 behind Nginx reverse proxy using docker in Windows. it is running properly at myhost:5000. but when accessing http://myhost:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration getting following response 
where the port number missing but working in development environment (ie: http://localhost:5000)

```
{
"issuer":"http://myhost",
"jwks_uri":"http://myhost/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks",
"authorization_endpoint":"http://myhost/connect/authorize",
"token_endpoint":"http://myhost/connect/token",
"userinfo_endpoint":"http://myhost/connect/userinfo",
"end_session_endpoint":"http://myhost/connect/endsession",
"check_session_iframe":"http://myhost/connect/checksession",
"revocation_endpoint":"http://myhost/connect/revocation",
"introspection_endpoint":"http://myhost/connect/introspect",
"frontchannel_logout_supported":true,
"frontchannel_logout_session_supported":true,
"backchannel_logout_supported":true,
"backchannel_logout_session_supported":true,    
}
```

I have tried following Identity server options **IssuerUri** and **PublicOrigin**, but response remains same.

Is there any other solution to get the response with the port number?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I was just facing this issue as well.
You will need to add the port in the Host headers in nginx.
`proxy_set_header   Host $host:$server_port;`

[Original Source](https://serverfault.com/questions/608448/nginx-reverse-proxy-requests-still-return-port-80)