# Identityserver from duende behind caddy has http in the openid config

Tags: docker, identityserver4, caddy

I am running an identity server from duende behind a caddy reverse proxy and both are running in a docer container. I also run a blazor server app in another container where I want to authenticate. Locally this is working fine, but when I run them behind the proxy, the `.well-known/openid-configuration` delivers `http://` endpoints and therefore the blazor app can not authenticate, because it does not allow authentication through http. The http is between caddy and the identity server. As this is running on a machine and is not crossing the evil net, I thought that might be ok. I think what I need to do is, generate a certificate for the identityserver and proxy via `https` instead of `http`. But I also do not want to generate certs by hand all the time or keep an eye out for that. A `UseHttpsRedirect()` in the startup made my service unavailable for caddy and just simply running it on 443 without a certificate also broke the call between caddy and the indentity server. I also found a tip where I could set the `IssuerUri` to `https` in the options, but this does not affect the other endpoints and therefore I still can not authenticate, because in the openid config there are still `http` endpoints (except the issuer)

Does anybody have an idea how I could do that and not create the certs by hand?

caddyfile:

```
identity.fading-flame.com {
    reverse_proxy http://identity-server-prod
}
```

Startup for IS

```
services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
                {
                    options.IssuerUri = $"https://{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("IDENTITY_BASE_URI")}";
                    options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;
                })
```

Or maybe something like that for caddy?
[Identityserver4 openid-configuration omits host port running nginx reverse proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52555915/identityserver4-openid-configuration-omits-host-port-running-nginx-reverse-proxy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I found a similar thread on GH that was with nginx, but the answer is still working with caddy.

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/324#issuecomment-324133883

Basically, before the identity server middleware, I have this one:

```
    app.Use((context, next) =>
    {
        context.Request.Scheme = "https";
        return next();
    });
    
    app.UseIdentityServer();
```

Then the openid config returns `https` endpoints and everything is fine. What was still missing for me was the same thing for the blazor server app, because I use the auth framework there aswell and the redirect url is `http` because of the same reason with caddy. So in the blazor app this fixed the callback from Identity server, pretty sure it has to be before authentication, but I did not test it out:

```
    app.Use((context, next) =>
    {
        context.Request.Scheme = "https";
        return next();
    });
    
    app.UseAuthentication();
```

Hope this helps someone some day ;)

Comment: I've tried, in local it's showing https in the discovery document. However when deployed in AWS Fargate cluster it still shows http. Do you know what could be messing with it? Do you use any additional forwarded headers?

Comment: I am running it on a private server, dont know if aws does something different on aws, but that would be weird. The order matters, though and if you have an `if (development)` somewhere that might be switched on a production build. Maybe run it locally in release and check?

Comment: I solved it. PathBase was messing up with the value, but setting the scheme to `https` works fine. Thanks